# Restricting a natural isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a natural isomorphism between functors $F,G:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$. Provided that $F$ and $G$ are functors $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ for its subcategory $\mathcal{D}$, is it necessarily a natural isomorphism in $\mathcal{D}$?

If not, which conditions we need to add to make sure it is a natural isomorphism in $\mathcal{D}$?

Answer (score 2):

No not necessarily. If $F$ and $G$ have codomain $\mathcal C$, but happen to land in $\mathcal D$, then a natural transformation between $F$ and $G$ has no reason to have its branches lie in $\mathcal D$. (An example: if $F=G$ is the identity on objects and sends every morphisms to zero in a pointed category, then any choice of arrows at each object gives a natural transformation $\alpha$, and if any of the chosen arrows are nonzero then $\alpha$ is not a natural transformation between $F$ and $G$ restricted to the codomain $\mathcal C_0$ of objects with zero morphisms only.)

If $\mathcal D$ is a *full* subcategory, then the arrows of $\alpha$ must lie in $\mathcal D$, and if they're isos in $\mathcal C$ they are in $\mathcal D$, so that the only restriction is that $\alpha$ and its inverse actually lie in $\mathcal D$.

Comment: It seems that you have misunderstood my question (or rather that I asked it wrongly). I have edited the question. Does your thesis hold nevertheless?

Comment: Also note that I misunderstand something related with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Monoidal_category#I_misunderstand_something

Comment: I ignored the domain because the domain is irrelevant to this. It seems rather obvious that if you restrict the domain of a functor and of a natural isomorphism you still get a natural isomorphism. Remember that a natural isomorphism is just a natural transformation all of whose arrows are isomorphisms-so you're really only talking about the codomain.